# How many items has been scraped per start_url

Tags: python, scrapy

I use scrapy to crawl 1000 urls and store scraped item in a mongodb. I'd to know how many items have been found for each url. From scrapy stats I can see `'item_scraped_count': 3500`
However, I need this count for each start_url separately. There is also `referer` field for each item that I might use to count each url items manually:

```
2016-05-24 15:15:10 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6w-_ucPV674> (referer: https://www.youtube.com/results?q=billys&sp=EgQIAhAB)
```

But I wonder if there is a built-in support from scrapy.

Comment: Maybe you could create a list or dictionary that increments each index or value every time it scrapes content for a specific link? I've never used scrapy before but this seems like a quick solution to your problem

Comment: Could you show your spider and the expected output? Thanks.

Comment: @FreddieV4 thanks, that would be a manual counting of referer but I prefer to do it in one batch at the end of the crawl.

Comment: @alecxe my spider is not something special just assume [this](https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot/blob/master/dirbot/spiders/dmoz.py). The output format could be anything something like  [{"url" : "http://www.dmoz.org/Python/Books" , "count" : "25"} , {"url" : "http://www.dmoz.org/Resources/", "count" : "50"}]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

challenge accepted!

there isn't something on `scrapy` that directly supports this, but you could separate it from your spider code with a [`Spider Middleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html):

**middlewares.py**

```
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class StartRequestsCountMiddleware(object):

    start_urls = {}

    def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
        for i, request in enumerate(start_requests):
            self.start_urls[i] = request.url
            request.meta.update(start_request_index=i)
            yield request

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        for output in result:
            if isinstance(output, Request):
                output.meta.update(
                    start_request_index=response.meta['start_request_index'],
                )
            else:
                spider.crawler.stats.inc_value(
                    'start_requests/item_scraped_count/{}'.format(
                        self.start_urls[response.meta['start_request_index']],
                    ),
                )
            yield output
```

Remember to activate it on `settings.py`:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    ...
    'myproject.middlewares.StartRequestsCountMiddleware': 200,
}
```

Now you should be able to see something like this on your spider stats:

```
'start_requests/item_scraped_count/START_URL1': ITEMCOUNT1,
'start_requests/item_scraped_count/START_URL2': ITEMCOUNT2,
```

Comment: it works like a charm. thanks! Only one thing that can be improved: this is not showing urls with 0 scraped item in the spider stats. Is there a simple way of showing those urls with ITEMCOUNT = 0?

Comment: you can also include in the stats with `set_value('mystat", 0)`, so in `process_start_requests`, add a line with `spider.crawler.stats.set_value("myurl", 0)`