# How to pass the start url in scrappy rules link extractor?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a set of start urls, like below:

```
start_urls = [www.example.com,www.example.com/ca,wwww.example.com/ap]
```

Now I have written code for extracting all the urls occurring inside each start_urls like below:

```
rules = (Rule(
    LinkExtractor(
        allow_domains = ('example.com'),
        attrs = ('href'),
        tags = ('a'),
        deny = (),
        deny_extensions = (),
        unique = True,
    ),
    callback = 'parseHtml', follow = True),)
```

In the `parseHtml` function, I am parsing the the content of the links.

Now in the above sites, I have common links occurring. For those common links I need to have some sort of identification to be done based on the `start_urls`.
How can I achieve this using scrappy?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could not use the `CrawlSpider` and pass the start_url information yourself from `start_requests` through all your callbacks
2. You could create a [`Spider Middleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#spider-middleware) to handle `start_requests` to do the same but without doing it directly on the spider, you can find a similar behaviour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37420626/858913)